# How to create boolean method using return true statement

Tags: java, methods, binary, boolean, return

I need to make a boolean method that takes in a string and checks if it is a binary number. If it is binary it should return true, if it contains anything other than 0s and 1s, return false.  Here is my code:

```
public static boolean CheckInputCorrect(String input) {
    int len = input.length();
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++)

        if(input.charAt(i) == '1' || input.charAt(i) == '0') {
            continue;
            return true;
        } else {
            break; 
            return false;
      }
 }
```

I suspect a syntax error, however no matter what I try it finds an error.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you expect `continue` and `break` to do?

Comment: You don't need break, or continue and you want to `return true` only after ALL the characters were ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the current character is a `1` or a `0`, then you can't make a decision yet; it's just good so far.

If it's not `1` and it's not `0`, then you can immediately return `false`.  Once you have run through the entire `String`, then you can return `true` after the `for` loop ends.

```
for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
{
    if(! (input.charAt(i) == '1' || input.charAt(i) == '0'))
    {
       return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 4):

Check each character and if it is *not* 0 or 1, then return `false` immediately. If you get through all the characters, return `true`:

```
public static boolean CheckInputCorrect(String input) {
    final int len = input.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        final char c = input.charAt(i);
        if (c != '1' && c != '0') {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

There's no need for `continue` or `break` statements. Certainly don't use `continue` or `break` just before another statement; that usually generates a "not reachable" compiler error.

Note that you could also do this test by using a regular expression:

```
public static boolean CheckInputCorrect(String input) {
    return input.matches("[01]*");
}
```

and if this is going to be called multiple times, it would be more efficient to compile the pattern:

```
private static Pattern zerosOrOnes = Pattern.compile("[01]*");

public static boolean CheckInputCorrect(String input) {
    return zerosOrOnes.matcher(input).matches();
}
```